# Why Klein-Gordon equation before QFT?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, resource-recommendations, education, klein-gordon-equation

**Note :** This is an edit of the original question.

**Previously (with some more elaboration of what I had in mind):** Peskin's QFT book starts with Klein Gordon equation, which is little taught for most people and thus physics of it is, probably, rather not helpful for learning QFT but it only served me as a toy object with simple Lagrangian.

The lack of physical intuition about it , e.g what does it do? How it  changes? What does it mean to be scalar quantity? Is it like a potential? Can we just define our own toy lagrangian and say this is a field? What are the rules to this? , was the thing making me ask this feels lacking context. (Imagine they started with E-M field, wouldn't that give so much intuition?)

And in addition, I asked for some resource recommendations. (below answers are for that)

Moreover, I stated for the intuition part, I have only seen Barton's Intro to String Theory 2nd ed discussing KGF a bit more in detail:

If you independently quantize relativistic point particle (from KGF) you can obtain (depending on your assumptions) the wavefunction to satisfy in lightcone gauge, natural units:

> $$ ( i\frac{\partial}{\partial t} - H ) | \Psi, t \rangle = 0$$
> where
> $$H = \frac{p^{+}(t)\cdot p^{-}(t)}{m^2}$$
> with momentum terms being light-cone momentum and product being product of 4-vectors.

Field equation for KGF, which on its own not talking about relativistic particle has the same equaition 'of motion' with $\psi$ replaced by $\phi$ , the field. There is also more correspondence, e.g between quantum states of both systems and this suggests that KGF might be the way to quantize relativistic point particle, and also contain multi-particle solutions.

You can read this on chp 11.

I think I actually answered my question, but in case there is more you could say I will post this as a question with the same title.

Comment: While Peskin is a great book for QFT, I'd imagine if this is your very first forey into QFT that there are many books which are far easier and serve as an actual introduction and bridge the gap beyween QM and QFT better. Especially at an undergrad level.

Comment: Do you know any good books that you could suggest? I (we) chose this book bcs it was most friendly as we heard and checked a bit

Comment: You can start with a more friendly QFT textbook like this one, "Student Friendly Quantum Field Theory Volume 1"

Comment: P&S is 800pages thick book, it has perhaps 15pages on KGE, the absolute minimum. Another book in particular on Relativistic Quantum Mechanics would be more useful. Nevertheless KGE is a good example how to (second) quantize fields. That's what is QFT about. Learn about how to quantize fields first. KGE is not just a relativistic generalization of SE. On the contrary it shows that the consideration of relativity requires new concepts which look strange at the beginning. QM is about 1particle, QFT about many particles which are related with fields.

Comment: To reopen this post (v2) consider to only ask 1 question.

Comment: *please let me know of latex for physicsstack* Here is a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: somehow mathjax was not working properly